# Python closes after running program with writing to file

Tags: python

Python keeps closing after I try and run a script. It runs fine and works perfect in my IDE, but when I run the .py from file explorer, it immediately closes, and doesn't write to the file as directed.
I want the program to delete all text on the file, then write 'ToWrite' 4 times.

```
my_file = open(r"C:\Users\shady\Desktop\copy\python\myfile.txt", "w")
my_file.write("")
my_file.close()

time = [1,1,1,1]
ToWrite = "hello\n"
for x in time:
    my_file = open("myfile.txt", "a")
    my_file.write(ToWrite)
    my_file.close()
```

I want the program to delete all text on the file, then write 'ToWrite' 4 times.

I tried removing these lines of code from my larger project, and it ran with no isues.

Comment: Your first reference to the file is an absolute path but your 2nd reference is a relative path, which means that Python is writing to the current working directory,  which for command-line execution is often not what novices expect. It works as you expect in your IDE because there you explicitly set the current working directory. Use an absolute path both times. And if you open the file in mode `"w"` instead of `"a"` then you won't have to explicitly zero it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are running this via the command prompt, and so should be able to see the error message. Please post that also. The main problem is that you are not escaping the backslash.
Try this:

```
my_file = open("C:\\Users\\shady\\Desktop\\copy\\python\\myfile.txt", "w")
```

or this:

```
my_file = open("C:/Users/shady/Desktop/copy/python/myfile.txt", "w")
```

or this:

```
import os
filepath = os.sep.join(["C:", "Users", "shady", "Desktop", "copy", "python", "myfile.txt"])
my_file = open(filepath,"w")
```

If you are not familiar with the command prompt. Open the Windows Start menu and type cmd then select the cmd prompt.
Inside here use cd to change the directory to where your python program is located, then run

```
py yourprogram.py
```

Comment: OP does not need to escape the backslash, because they are using a raw string, as is generally recommended for Windows filenames.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I overlooked the 'r'